# How can I use these fonts?

Tags: fonts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find out what fonts are used in a document/picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45919/how-do-i-find-out-what-fonts-are-used-in-a-document-picture)

How can I use [these](http://essay.utwente.nl/58346/1/scriptie_Chimento.pdf) fonts? Is the text font the font Palatino also used  in `classcthesis`? And what is the math font?

Comment: It is worth noting, for others, that the linked PDF is 13 Mb!

Comment: i have try CTRL+D but there are some fonts in the fonts tab so i don't understand what is the fonts really used...

Comment: @FormlessCloud It's Palatino, which there are various ways to use. I go for `\usepackage{mathpazo}` for most of my stuff, but might then load the new `tgpagella` package to use the TeX Gyre version of Palatino.